# `intent.getAction()` is null in `onNewIntent()` when handling NFC after updating to API 33

Tags: android, nfc, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

I've just updated an older application and upgraded the `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersoin` from 30 to 33.

After the update, existing NFC functionality seemed to stop working. It was found that the `intent.getAction()` method was returning `null` inside `onNewIntent()`, which is called when an NFC tag is scanned. Here's some relevant code:

```java
@Override                                                                                             
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {                                                                                                                                  
    String action = intent.getAction(); // This is null now!                                                              
    boolean correctAction = NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)                          
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action);                                      
    if (correctAction) {                                                                              
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);                                    
        if (mTask != null && !Sensor.getId(tag).equals(mTask.getSensorId())) {                        
            showAlert(R.string.wrong_sensor_error);                                                   
        } else {                                                                                      
            Parcelable[] rawMessages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            handleNFC(tag, rawMessages);                                                              
        }                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                 
}
```

Here's some setup code with some irrelevant methods removed:

```java
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_TASK = "extra_task";
    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    private IntentFilter[] mFilters;
    private String[][] mTechLists;
    private AlertDialog mNfcAlert;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpNFC();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        validateToken();
        if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            try {
                mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters, mTechLists);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                setUpNFC();
            }
        } else {
            showNfcAlert();
        }
    }

    private void setUpNFC() {
        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 415, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        } else {
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 415, intent, 0);
        }
        IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndef.addDataType("*/*");
        } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
        }
        mFilters = new IntentFilter[] {ndef};
        String[] r11 = new String[] {NfcA.class.getName(), Ndef.class.getName(), IsoDep.class.getName()};
        String[] r12 = new String[] {NfcA.class.getName(), IsoDep.class.getName()};
        mTechLists = new String[][] {r11, r12};
        mNfcAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(R.string.nfc_disabled)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.nfc_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    // ....
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).create();
    }
    // ......
}
```

Were there some sort of changes to NFC functionality in Android in the newer versions? Why does this code work when targeting API 30, but not API 33?

Comment: There have been some undocumented changes like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695662/securityexception-while-ndef-connect-on-android-13

Comment: Thank you! The issue I reported did not involve an exception, though that would have made things easier. I believe I may have found a resolution to the issue; please see my answer.

Comment: The security exception was more a general comment that Google does make changes and then not tell anybody. I forgot about the Mutable change, as I use the better and more reliable `enableReaderMode` instead of the old Intent based system.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I may have found a resolution.

Android 11 and above require a `PendingIntent` to be explicitely marked as mutable or immutable (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_MUTABLE). Prior to Android 11, a `PendingIntent` was considered mutable by default.

It seems likely that the NFC flow modifies the `Intent` within a `PendingIntent`, in order to add fields such as the field returned from `Intent#getAction()`. If the `PendingIntent` is marked as immutable via `FLAG_IMMUTABLE`, the `Intent` within it cannot be modified and thus certain fields inside the `Intent` are not populated.

That's the theory, at least.

Comment: This is exactly what I ran into, and it makes sense.